# ColdFusion and Streaming APIs... (i.e. Twitter)

Tags: coldfusion, http-streaming, cfhttp

Has anyone had any luck using ColdFusion as a way to collect data via streaming APIs?

i.e. - https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api

I know the best option is to use an app that literally sits on the server monitoring these portals.  Just curious if anyone has done anything using CF yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aaron Longnion built refynr.com using CF9. It's a service that collects users' Twitter streams based on supplied criteria. I imagine he's down something like you describe.

However, I'd look into the new web socket functionality built into ColdFusion 10 and see if that makes consuming streaming APIs any easier.

http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/coldfusion10/

Comment: Refyner uses monkehTweets (monkehtweet.riaforge.org). At the moment this does nto support the streaming API. This is something I'm working on.

Answer (score 1):

If you know a bit of Java, it may not be too difficult to use [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html#streaming), and build an event gateway for your CF app to consume the stream.

If you want to go the web socket route, see: [Twitter + HTML5 webSocket API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313736/twitter-html5-websocket-api)